# Getting the name of an element from a ln array

Tags: java, android, arrays, image

I'm new to android studio and I'm trying to make guessing game where a random image is selected from an array of images stored in drawables.
The user then guesses the brand of car in the image from a spinner menu.
I don't understand how to get the name of the image from the array to compare it to the selection from the spinner

My array is structured as
Integer[] carImages = {R.drawable.audi1, R.drawable.audi2} etc
Is there a way to return the "audi1" etc?

Comment: No.  `audi` is a name of a variable, it's not even 'in' the array.  The array merely contains references that refer to the same things that some variable also refers to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From what you have said my solution won't work, so I will need to think of another way of approaching this.